# Efficiently name columns base on simple JSON object in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple JSON object:

```
"myObject": {
"var1": "analytics#filterExpression",
"var2": string,
"var3": string
}
```

How can I loop through this object, extract each variable name and pass them in my spreadsheet.

So far I'm doing this manually like this

`sheet.appendRow(['var1', 'var3', 'var3']);`

This is not very dynamic...

Comment: Do you always want them in that order?

Comment: if order  matters, then arrays should be used to store data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this sample script? In this sample, `Object.keys` is used.

#### Sample script:

```
// const string = "###";  // Please set "string".
// const sheet = ###;  // Please set "sheet".

const obj = {
  "myObject": {
    "var1": "analytics#filterExpression",
    "var2": string,
    "var3": string
  }
};
sheet.appendRow(Object.keys(obj.myObject));
```

#### Note:

- About the order of each properties in the object of `myObject`,

  > The iteration order for objects follows a certain set of rules since ES2015, but it does not (always) follow the insertion order. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/7108653)

  - Please be careful this.
- If you want to sort the values, please sort the values of `Object.keys(obj.myObject)` and put to the sheet.

  - It's like `sheet.appendRow(Object.keys(obj.myObject).sort());`

#### Reference:

- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)